# How to remove top border of persistentFooterButtons in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using persistentFooterButtons and i wanna remove the top border of its.
Anyone knows how ?

My code:

```
 persistentFooterButtons: [
        Center(
          child: TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              
            ),
              onPressed: () {
                print("press the filter btn");
              },
              child: Text("Filter")),
        )
      ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You could do something like this:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Text("Body"),
    persistentFooterButtons: [
      Center(
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(),
          onPressed: () {
            print("press the filter btn");
          },
          child: Text("Filter"),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

`dividerColor: Colors.transparent,` sets the divider / top border to transparent

Comment: If you **already have a Theme** declared (I was using `Theme.of(context).textTheme` for styling purposes) **try to use** 
`Theme.of(context).copyWith()` 
**instead of** `ThemeData().copyWith()`

Comment: True. Thanks @berkaykurkcu. I updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution if the solutions above are not working:
Wrap your Scaffold with local Theme widget and change the `DividerThemeData`

```
  Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
    child: Scaffold(.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `Border` is actually hard-coded for this scenario. Looking at the source code of `Scaffold`, we can see how it's implemented:

```dart
if (widget.persistentFooterButtons != null) {
  _addIfNonNull(
    children,
    Container(
      /// Here is the non-conditional [Border] being set for the top side
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          top: Divider.createBorderSide(context, width: 1.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: ButtonBar(
          children: widget.persistentFooterButtons!,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ...
```

But as you can see, the implementation of these buttons is pretty straight forward. As an easy fix, you can wrap the content of your `Scaffold` with a `Stack` and use the same implementation to achieve the same more customised (first step without the `Border`)

Something like this (might have to be adjusted to work as you want it to):

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: [
      /// Your usual body part of the [Scaffold]
      ...
      /// Now here your own version of the bottom buttons just as the original implementation in [Scaffold]
      SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: ButtonBar(
          children: [
            /// Place buttons or whatever you want here
            ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. 
But it doesn't satisfy me yet. 
I want it stay persistent and my user can click even easily whenever first open it.